# Can't override Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento-community, override-block

I have a problem to `rewrite/override` `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar.`

Here is my code:

> **etc/modules/Codesky_CatalogProduct.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
      <modules>
        <Codesky_CatalogProduct>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Codesky_CatalogProduct>
      </modules>
</config>
```

> **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codesky_CatalogProduct>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Codesky_CatalogProduct>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalogproduct>
                <class>Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block</class>
            </catalogproduct>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> **Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block_Product_List_Toolbar.php**

```
class Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
{
    /**
     * Retrieve available limits for current view mode
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAvailableLimit()
    {
        return array(30 => 30, 60 => 60, 90 => 90);
    }
}
```

**Why it's not working. Magento still use method getAvailableLimit() from core file.**

Comment: Have you tried clear cache and session?  This code, you are trying for basic category view page, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use below `config.xml` and make path according to `Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar` and override your function whatever you want :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Codesky_CatalogProduct>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Codesky_CatalogProduct>
  </modules>
  <global>
  <blocks>
      <catalogproduct>
        <class>Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block</class>
      </catalogproduct>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_toolbar>Codesky_CatalogProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```